# What is the difference between num[:] and num?

Tags: python, arrays

```
nums = []
vals = nums
vals.append(1)
```

the result shows nums and vals are of same length but

```
nums = []
vals = nums[:]
vals.append(1)
```

this shows vals is longer than num

Comment: somebody please upvote it i can't further ask anymore questions in stack overfllow.

Comment: Done with the upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `[:]` you creating a new `list` containing the same values as `nums`, but that new `list` is *not* the same object as `nums`. That's why in your second example `vales` is longer than `nums`: it is not the same object.

```python
initial = []
a = initial
b = initial[:]

assert a is initial
assert b is not initial
```

More precisely, [as stated in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), indexing with `[:]` is equivalent to `copy` the list:

```python
initial = []

# these are equivalent
a = initial[:]
b = initial.copy()

assert a is not initial
assert b is not initial
```

Comment: Not exact: you are creating a **new list** with the same values.

Comment: Correct, I should have been more precise, fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

With:

```py
nums = []
vals = nums
vals.append(1)
```

You have 2 references pointing the same list in memory.

With:

```py
nums = []
vals = nums[:]
vals.append(1)
```

You have 2 distinct lists in memory: the `vals` is a copy of the `nums` list (which is empty).

Writing `vals = nums[:]` is the same as writing `vals = list(nums)`: you create a new list (with the same items inside).

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = []
vals = nums[:]
vals.append(1)
```

In second case you are creating new list vals from nums. Both the list will point out to separate memory location and hence changes made on vals list will not made any impact on nums list.

```
nums = []
vals = nums
vals.append(1)
```

Whereas in first case you are copying list nums to vals and both vals and nums are pointing out to same heap storage location.
So changes made to vals will automatically affects to nums.

For more you can read the article- 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html